# Android Current window check

Tags: android, android-view

How to make it properly? I mean, I need check what is current view, and change menu option depend on currernt view? Any ideas?

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        if(getWindow().equals(R.id.additional_content)) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test2, menu);

        } else {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test1, menu);

        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

invalidateOptionsMenu() was added to give us the ability to force onCreateOptionsMenu() to be called again.  onPrepareOptionsMenu() is still called every time you call the menu.

What you are trying to achieve above is a good example of when to use  invalidateOptionsMenu() but because of backwards compatibility you will need to do both:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        selectMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        selectMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}

private void selectMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    if (locked) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.changing_menu2, menu);
    }
    else {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.changing_menu1, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reply for question using my example?

Comment: You are in the same activity? or Are they 2 different activities?

Comment: If in the same activity, check the visibility of the views are re-inflate the menus

Comment: Can you prepare some example?